# Watir-Webdriver how can I get embedded pdf text in Chrome using a Watir Browser

Tags: ruby, pdf, automated-tests, watir-webdriver

For some reason I can't access the PDF text in Chrome's built in pdf viewer anymore.

```
@browser.text
=> ""
```

The PDF is embedded and I haven't been able to easily get it with `Net/HTTP` gets or `curb` or `httparty`. But it is showing up plain as day in the browser...

Do I have to do something with `@browser.driver#some_method`? or maybe change the capabilities hash before `Watir::Browser.new :chrome`?

What are people doing now to check PDF text in web apps with the recent changes to Chrome and Chromedriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watir is great for handling html, but isn't designed to deal with formats like pdf. If you want to parse pdf files, you can try something like [pdf-reader](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader):

```
require 'pdf-reader'
require 'open-uri'

io = open(@browser.url)
reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)
reader.pages.first.text
```